# Why PrimeFaces prints multiple messages?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to save something from a form. When pressing Save application successfully saves the inserted information and prints a success message. The problem is that for some reason it also prints an empty box with no message at all.

This is the code that I use for saving.

```
public void saveAndNew() {

    IObject createdObj = null;
    List<IAttributeObject> allAttributesList = new ArrayList<IAttributeObject>();

    for (List attributeList : groupToFieldListMap.values()) {
        for (Object object : attributeList) {
            IAttributeObject attributeObject = (IAttributeObject) object;
            if (attributeObject.getAttributeDescriptor().getDataType() == DataTypeConstants.THUMBNAIL) {
                if (null != img) {
                    try { // add the cropped image bytes
                        attributeObject.setAttributeValue(img);
                    } catch (M3Exception e) {
                        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, user);
                    }
                }
            }
            allAttributesList.add(attributeObject);
        }
    }

    // RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        createdObj = user.getApiSession().createObject(getIdByType(getSelectedVal()), allAttributesList);
        if (createdObj != null) {
            user.addRecentlyVisitedToServer(createdObj);
            // Messages.addGlobalInfo("Object " + createdObj.getNumber() + "
            // created");
            // requestContext.update(":mainMenu");
            init(this.selectedVal);
            // requestContext.reset("createForm");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "PrimeFaces Rocks."));
        }
    } catch (M3Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, user);
        // requestContext.update("createForm:tree");
    }

}
```

Just before the catch I am printing the message and the result is

[image]

This is the code in xhtml

```
<h:form id="createForm">
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="colOneTop, colTwoTop, colTop">....
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Comment out both JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, user); 's in your code and see if you still get the error message. If so, probably caused by some "required" element in your xhtml..

Comment: That did not work =(

Comment: What do you mean that did not work, you are still seeing the empty error message?

Comment: @KorayTugay , Ok the problem was that I had a method somewhere deep that was failing into a catch that catches a null pointer and the error that returns is null. But it was completely my fault.

Comment: So effectively PrimeFaces does exactely as it was told to do. Next time e.g. try with a `h:messages` and create a [mcve]. By removing stuff you'll narrow down the problem and very often find the cause.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.